# To Add multiple values from different columns from two tables

Tags: sql

```
Table A1                            Table B1

A --100 id =1                      A --100 id=1

B -- 100 id =2                     A -100  id=1

C -- 200 id=3                      A - 100 id =1
```

Need to sum all values from two tables where id =1.

```
select (SUM(A1.A) + SUM(nvl(B1.A,0))) SUM from A1 a, B1 b where a.id='1' AND b.id='1';
```

I am getting sum as 600 but it should be 400

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT id, SUM(A) as Totals FROM
(
 SELECT id, A FROM A1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, A FROM B1
) AS tblData
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `CROSS JOIN` ( Cartesian product ) so you get 600..

You can try this to use `UNION` combine two table.

```
SELECT SUM(T.Totle)
FROM 
(
    select SUM(A1.A) Totle from A1 a where a.id='1'
    UNION ALL
    select SUM(B1.A) Totle from B1 b where b.id='1'
) T
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da691/7)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT SUM(A) FROM A1 WHERE ID = 1), 0) +
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(A) FROM B1 WHERE ID = 1), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do by this way

```
    select sum(A) as total
    from
    (
        select A 
        from A1 where id = 1                           
        union all
        select A 
        from B1 where id = 1
    ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that doesn't use subqueries (although I am not recommending it):

```
select coalesce(sum(a.a), 0) + coalesce(sum(b.b), 0)
from a full outer join
     b
     on 1 = 0 
where a.id = 1 or b.id = 1;
```